# Query data returned by CURSOR FOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need some assistance with the following PL/SQL code which displays the time difference in minutes between two date values. The first part before the IF-Statement returns the needed information, but the challenge comes in when i'm trying to write an IF-Statement to display the time difference for only those jobs that have exceeded 15 Minutes then send Email notification through Exchange Server.

Your assistance is appreciated in advance.

```
Declare

l_found boolean :=false;

Cursor C5 

is 
    (SELECT CASE LENGTH(JCSBMTIME) 
     WHEN 0 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('000000',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  
     ,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     WHEN 1 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('00000',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  
     ,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     WHEN 2 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('0000',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  ,'DD-
     MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     WHEN 3 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('000',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  ,'DD-
     MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     WHEN 4 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('00',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  ,'DD-
     MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     WHEN 5 THEN
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('0',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  ,'DD-
     MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440),2)
     ELSE
     round(((sysdate - to_date 
     (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(to_number(JCSBMDATE)+1900000),'YYYYDDD') || ' ' ||  
     to_char(to_date(CONCAT('',JCSBMTIME),'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')  ,'DD-MON-
     YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 1440 ),2)
     END AS "DATETIME_DIFF", 
     JCUSER, JCJOBNBR, JCSBMTIME FROM SVM900E1.F986110 
     WHERE JCSBMDATE = (TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYDDD')-1900000) 
     AND JCJOBSTS in ('P','S','W')); 

Begin

    For Y in C5 

Loop 

l_found := true;

    dbms_output.put_line(Y.DATETIME_DIFF||' '||Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' 
    '||Y.JCSBMTIME); 
End loop;

if not l_found

Then

    dbms_output.put_line('No records found');

End if;

Case Y.DATETIME_DIFF  when > 15 

Then 

   dbms_output.put_line(Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' '||Y.JCSBMTIME);

Else 'No records';

End case;

End;
```

Comment: What is the issue? Are you having an error' If so, which one? Or are you having an unwanted behaviour?

Comment: I haven't read all the code, bu you are trying to use a CASE when you need an IF and you're referring to the loop variable Y from outside the loop. Also, what should the ELSE do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to your Y iterator scope. You are trying  to use it out of loop statement.

You code should be like this. I omit part of cursor declaration
    --at first init to false
    l_found := false;

```
 for Y in your_cursor loop 
 -- if we are in loop , we are found a record , change value to true
 l_found := true;

  check conditions, do output etc...

 end loop;

-- if cursor have no result 
if not l_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No records found');
end if;
```

Comment: Have revised my code to look like this but now its returning no data nor message.

Comment: revised it but now the program executes then returns nothing        
Begin
    For Y in C5 
Loop 

--l_found := true;
    dbms_output.put_line(Y.DATETIME_DIFF||' '||Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' '||Y.JCSBMTIME); 
    
if  Y.DATETIME_DIFF   > 15 
Then 
   dbms_output.put_line(Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' '||Y.JCSBMTIME); 
   else
   dbms_output.put_line('No records found: nothing above 15');
   
end if;
/*if not l_found
Then
    dbms_output.put_line('No records found');
End if;*/

end loop;

End;

Comment: if your cursor has no result set, then you can't check  "if not l_found " expression inside loop, it should be check out of loop operator.

Comment: 3.23 KALELIJ    2217639 83755
No records found: nothing above 15
6.2 OMONDIR    2217635 83457
No records found: nothing above 15

Comment: After removing the l_found boolean :=false part, this is the output im getting. I shouldn't be seeing No records found if data above 15 minutes is available.                                                                                                        3.23 KALELIJ    2217639 83755
No records found: nothing above 15
6.2 OMONDIR    2217635 83457
No records found: nothing above 15

Comment: You should not remove that code, see changes in my answer

Comment: This is the code                                                                                                                                              
 Begin
    For Y in C5 
Loop 

    dbms_output.put_line(Y.DATETIME_DIFF||' '||Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' '||Y.JCSBMTIME); 
    
if  Y.DATETIME_DIFF   >= 15 
Then 
   dbms_output.put_line(Y.JCUSER||' ' ||Y.JCJOBNBR||' '||Y.JCSBMTIME); 
   else
   dbms_output.put_line('No records found: nothing above 15');
   
end if;
end loop;
End;

Comment: I Only want to see results of the if Y.DATETIME_DIFF>= 15

Comment: Your query can return a set of rows some of then can satisfy your condition DATETIME_DIFF>= 15  some can't. Move condition to sql query or remove else dbms_output.put_line('No records found: nothing above 15'); from loop, or check if you didn't find rows match your condition before  output 'No records found: nothing above 15', .. etc.  There is a lot of variants, some effective, same not. You decide which one you want.